# Append items to Pandas Dataframe to behave like a print statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that is created by reading a text file. The dataframe has `"\n"` which I want to behave like a newline character in the dataframe. Instead, it just shows as `'SOMEtext\n'`. I want the `\n` to behave like it should. This will make the content in the dataframe more readable. All help is highly appreciated.

This is what a section looks like in list form:

```
['dnPrefix SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ON_TORONTO,MeContext=NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'managedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'managedElementType 5GRadioNode\n', 'networkManagedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'release 19.Q2\n', 'siteLocation \n', 'userLabel NR01_T23MG_C3144\n']
```

I want it to look like this in the dataframe:

```
dnPrefix SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ON_TORONTO,MeContext=NR01_T23MG_C3144

managedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144

managedElementType 5GRadioNode

networkManagedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144

release 19.Q2

siteLocation 

userLabel NR01_T23MG_C3144
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip):

```
list1 = ['dnPrefix SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ON_TORONTO,MeContext=NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'managedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'managedElementType 5GRadioNode\n', 'networkManagedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'release 19.Q2\n', 'siteLocation \n', 'userLabel NR01_T23MG_C3144\n']
>>> pd.DataFrame([i.rstrip() for i in list1])
                                               0
0  dnPrefix SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ON...
1                  managedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144
2                     managedElementType 5GRadioNode
3           networkManagedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144
4                                      release 19.Q2
5                                       siteLocation
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what if I want to add all items in that list into once cell. So they all fall under the "0" cell. Not 1 through 5.

Comment: @SaadShan I think I got what you're trying to get. See the columns, they are strings. Now think what you're trying to get. They will have to be strings, and if they'll be strings, you cannot just force '\n' to make a new line in the string since it doesn't get explicitly printed.

Comment: If you want all of them in one object, you can just add all those strings to make a mega string, and then put it in the dataframe constructor.

Comment: @SaadShan  I'd be like this: df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ''.join(list1)}, index = ['0'])

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop the list to get each element

```
List = ['dnPrefix SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ON_TORONTO,MeContext=NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'managedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'managedElementType 5GRadioNode\n', 'networkManagedElementId NR01_T23MG_C3144\n', 'release 19.Q2\n', 'siteLocation \n', 'userLabel NR01_T23MG_C3144\n']

for i in List:
    print(i)
```